# to throw, to return or to errno?

Tags: errno

i am creating a system. What i want to know is if a msg is unsupported what should it do? should i throw saying unsupported msg? should i return 0 or -1? or should i set an errno (base->errno_). Some messages i wouldnt care if there was an error (such as setBorderColour). Others i would (addText or perhaps save if i create a save cmd).

I want to know what the best method is for 1) coding quickly 2) debugging 3) extending and maintenance. I may make debugging 3rd, its hard to debug ATM but thats bc there is a lot of missing code which i didnt fill in. Actual bugs arent hard to correct. Whats the best way to let the user know there is an error?

The system works something like this but not exactly the same. This is C style and mycode has a bunch of inline functions that wrap settext(const char*text){ to msg(this, esettext, text)

```
Base base2, base;
base = get_root();
base2 = msg(base, create, BASE_TYPE);
msg(base2, setText, "my text");
const char *p = (const char *)msg(base2, getText);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally if it's C++, prefer exceptions unless performance is critical or unless you may be running in an environment (e.g. an embedded platform) that does not support exceptions. Exceptions are by far the best choice for debugging because they are very noticeable when they occur and are ignored. Further, exceptions are self-documenting. They have their own type name and usually a contained message that explains the error. Return codes and errno require separate code definitions and some kind of out-of-band way of communicating what the codes mean in any given context (e.g. man pages, comments).

For coding quickly, return codes are probably easier since they don't involve potentially defining your own exception types, and often the error checking code is not as verbose as with exceptions. But of course the big risk is that it is much easier to silently ignore error return codes, leading to problems that may not be noticed until well after they occur, making debugging and maintenance a nightmare.

Try to avoid ever using errno, since it's very error-prone itself. It's a global, so you never know who is resetting it, and it is most definitively *not* thread safe.

**Edit:** I just realized you meant an errno member variable and not the C-style errno. That's better in that it's not global, but you still need additional constructs to make it thread safe (if your app is multi-threaded), and it retains all the problems of a return code.

Comment: C-style errno is thread-safe; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449778/is-there-a-way-to-use-errno-safely-in-a-multi-threaded-application (but I agree that "It's a global, so you never know who is resetting it").

Answer (score 2):

Returning an error code requires discipline because the error code must be explicitly checked and then passed up.  We wrote a large C-based system that used this approach and it took a while to remove all the "lost" errors.  We eventually developed some techniques to catch this problem (such as storing the error code in a thread-global location and checking at the top level to see that the returned error code matched the saved error code).

Exception handling is easier to code quickly because if you're writing code and you're not sure how to handle the error, you can just let it propagate upwards (assuming you're not using Java where you have to deal with checked exceptions).  It's better for debugging because you can get a stack trace of where the exception occurred (and because you can build in top level exception handlers to catch problems that should have been caught elsewhere).  It's better for maintaining because if you've done things right, you'll be notified of problem faster.

However, there are some design issues with exception handling, and if you get it wrong, you'll be worse off.  In short, if you're writing code that you don't know how to handle an exception, you should let it propagate up.  Too many coders trap errors just to convert the exception and then rethrow it, resulting in spaghetti exception code that sometimes loses information about the original cause of the problem.  This assumes that you have exception handlers at the top level (entry points).

Answer (score 0):

Personally when it comes to output graphics, I feel a silent fail is fine.  It just makes your picture wrong.

Graphical errors are super easy to spot anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would add an errno to your Base struct if it is pure 'C'. If this is C++ I'd throw an exception.

It depends on how 'fatal' these errors are. Does the user really need to see the error, or is it for other developers edification?

For maintainability you need to clearly document the errors that can occur and include clear examples of error handling.