# Is there a way to use errno safely in a multi-threaded application?

Tags: c, errno

If you are writing a multi-threaded application that uses system/library calls that make use of errno to indicate the error type, is there a safe way to use errno? If not, is there some other way to indicate the type of error that occurred rather than just that an error has occurred?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If your standard library is multithread aware, then it probably has a `#define` that changes `errno` into a function call that returns a thread-local error return value. However, to use this you generally *must* include `<errno.h>`, rather than relying on an `extern` declaration.

I found an article [Thread-safety and POSIX.1](http://www.unix.org/whitepapers/reentrant.html) which addresses this very question.

Comment: Thanks!  A quick check in /usr/include/bits/errno.h confirmed that errno is indeed defined to be per-thread when using threads, on my Ubundu machine.

Answer (score 19):

`man errno` says:

> errno is defined by the ISO C standard
>   to be  a  modifiable  lvalue  of type 
>   int,  and  must not be explicitly
>   declared; errno may be a macro. errno
>   is thread-local; setting it in one
>   thread  does  not  affect  its value
>   in any other thread.