# Is it required for me to add a _REENTRANT macro during compile time to make my errno thread safe?

Tags: c, multithreading, compiler-construction, errno

Is it required for me to add a _REENTRANT macro during compile time to make my errno thread safe?

If no, is it the case for all versions of gcc / linux / solaris or is it required for certain old versions?

I recently tested a piece of code where _REENTRANT was not used and found the errno behaving in an undefined fahsion in multi thread environment? But, after adding _REENTRANT everything was working fine. The Environment was Solaris.

But, the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694164/is-errno-thread-safe) doesn't seem to say it is mandatory to add _REENTRANT. I am a little confused.

Also, apart from _REENTRANT should I add be adding any other options or libs to ensure my application has a thread safe errno?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In practice, `_REENTRANT` is legacy junk from a time when threads were considered an extension hacked on top of existing implementations, and the default behavior of the standard library was not thread-safe. It should not be needed on modern implementations, and it was never standard. (Note that it's also a misnomer, since *reentrant* and *thread-safe* have radically different meanings.)

In theory, POSIX requires you to query and use the following configuration options via `getconf` if you're compiling a threaded program:

- `POSIX_V7_THREADS_CFLAGS`
- `POSIX_V7_THREADS_LDFLAGS`

On the other hand, gcc has its own conflicting "portable" way to request thread support: the `-pthread` option, which normally adds any predefined macros and libraries needed for threads to work.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you need to compile with an option like `-mt` `-pthread` `-thread` (that is true for Sun CC and, for some platforms, for gcc).  With this option you get the define that you need.  If you don't use it, you may link the wrong library or even get code generation problem (such as no protection for static variable intialisation).