# How to determine whether a POSIX function is re-entrant or not?

Tags: posix, reentrancy

While writing directory iterator, I discovered that `readdir` function is not re-entrant. [`readdir_r`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir_r.html) function *seems* re-entrant version of that, but I don't know how to confirm this. Though `readdir` is explicitly marked non-reentrant, but there's no mention for `readdir_r`.

Is there a way to check re-entrancy of specific POSIX function? How to check re-entrancy of a POSIX function?

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a POSIX.1c policy for re-entrancy.](http://www.unix.org/whitepapers/reentrant.html)

Here's my summary.

- All functions are re-entrant by default.
- Some functions cannot be re-entrant due to various reasons. They will have separated re-entrant version. They are also explicitly marked.
- Some functions implies huge performance penalty for reentrancy. They will have separated non-reentrant version for single-threaded performance by sacrificing safety. They are also explicitly marked.

---

[Here's another caveat claim.](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/realtime/restricted/notes/pthreads.html)

Cited from the text.

> Header Files you Need for Thread Programming
>
> ```
> #define _REENTRANT
> #include <pthread.h>
> #include <sched.h>
> ```
>
> _REENTRANT indicates that the reentrant (i.e. thread safe) versions of the standard libraries should be used.
>
> The header file pthread.h defines the POSIX thread API.
>
> The header file sched.h defines the process and thread scheduling API.
>   Of the functions explained here, only `sched_yield()` requires it.

---

Anyway, there's another claim of these steps are not required anymore: *[Is it required for me to add a _REENTRANT macro during compile time to make my errno thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047333/is-it-required-for-me-to-add-a-reentrant-macro-during-compile-time-to-make-my-e)* It seems we don't need to define `_REENTRANT` anymore.

---

The term *reentrancy* is a legacy term from single threaded environment. Anyway, POSIX.1c presumes multi-threaded environment, and it silently assumes *re-entering from other thread* cases.