# Should I set errno?

Tags: c, errno

I'm writing a module which exports an interface similar to `send` and `recv`.

Since those functions are supposed to return respectively the number of sent and received bytes, I cannot do proper error management as I would do normally (i.e. using enumeratives and returning mnemonic values).

In a situation like this should I set `errno` as the standard library does? If so, since `errno` is thread specific, is there a particular way of writing on it, or can I simply assign a value to it?

**Edit:** experimenting it I noticed that setting `errno` by assignment is working. Still: is this safe and portable for any system?

Comment: For more than you ever wanted to know about `errno` and the C standards, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945486/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is a bit old, but [errno - manual section 3](http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno) says that you can directly assign to it, even though it is a macro, and it will be thread local

Answer (score 27):

Not only *can* you set `errno`, in many cases you **should** set `errno`. When calling some library functions you can only reliably detect an error if you first set `errno` to zero. [See `strtol` for an example](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtol.html).

From the POSIX specification of `strtol`:

> [CX] [Option Start] The strtol() function shall not change the setting of errno if successful.
>
> Since 0, {LONG_MIN} or {LLONG_MIN}, and {LONG_MAX} or {LLONG_MAX} are returned on error and are also valid returns on success, an application wishing to check for error situations should set errno to 0, then call strtol() or strtoll(), then check errno. [Option End]

Answer (score 10):

Actually, you probably *can* do "proper" (as you put it) error management since you return an `int`.

Just use non-negative values for the number of bytes read or written and negative values for error codes. You don't *have* to limit yourself to `-1`:

```
enum myerrors {
    ERR_NO_MEMORY    = -1,
    ERR_BAD_ARGS     = -2,
    ERR_CPU_EXPLODED = -3,
    // and so on
};
```

However, setting `errno` in the fashion you want is valid. The standard states that `errno` expands to a modifiable lvalue, meaning you can set it. From `C1x/n1425, 7.5 Errors <errno.h>`:

> ... and `errno` which expands to a modifiable lvalue that has type int, the value of which is set to a positive error number by several library functions.

Answer (score 7):

You can just assign a value to `errno`, but keep in mind that there are other ways to signal an error which, depending on your situation, may be more suitable:

1. Do not return the number of bytes read, but instead have an *output parameter* with type `int *` (or `size_t *` or whatever you use). You can then return an error code.
2. Assuming that your return type is a signed type and that a negative sent or received amount of bytes does not make sense, use negative values to signal the respective error conditions.

Comment: `errno` is used by nearly all functions in POSIX (except ones which return the error code and a few weird exceptions), not just low-level stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can assign to it, and yes, the assignment will be thread-safe.  See [Is errno thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694164/is-errno-thread-safe)

Answer (score 2):

From: http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc700/html/lr1/errno.htm

> The only portable values for `errno` are `EDOM` and `ERANGE`

So that answers your portability question.

Comment: I was more interested in the technical detail of assigning it, yet I didn't expect this kind of portability issue! :)

Comment: @Dacav - I don't think there's any special way you have to set it...you can just assign to it...I'd use the given enumeration values defined in `errno.h` if possible.

Comment: That list isn't quite complete, `EILSEQ` is mandated by the standard.

Comment: @prelic My question about setting it comes from the fact that it's a thread-specific global variable implemented by using macros. +1 for the enumeration values (which of course is strictly needed if you want meaningful values!)

Comment: @R.. As I read more, I'm seeing that...not sure if that article is outdated or just wrong.

Comment: Well POSIX is a separate standard from ISO C. It's true that ISO C doesn't define many errno values, but it does define a third one, `EILSEQ`.