# What should be the initial value for return status in C?

Tags: c, macros, return, status

Error handling code for any general function follows this template
Two questions from my end--

1. What should be the default FAILURE value? (1 to keep up with the main or 0, or  -1 to avoid all the confusion)
2. What should be the initial value of status? (FAIL or PASS)

Code:

```
#define FAILURE 0  //or shall it be 1 for success and 0 for failure
#define SUCCESS 1

int DoSomething() {
    int status = FAILURE;  //or shall we assign success by default?

    if (error1)
        return FAIL_A
    if (error2)
        return FAIL_B

    return SUCCESS;
}

int GetItDone() {
   status = FAIL;

   Status = DoSomething();
   if (PASS != status) //likewise many calls can happen later
     goto END;

END:
  return status;
    }
```

The status bubble up through function calls.

Comment: Don't trust your functions, start with FAILURE - that's what I do

Comment: You can't start with failure if, for example, you have to loop and look for a failing condition. The code above doesn't make sense because `status` is never actually used.

Comment: There are like a dozen different ways to handle returning error values. You could perhaps provide a bit more context... Like, do you also return result value, or only success / error code? Also, try to make the code sample to make sense... now `status` is never used, so the code snippet is just confusing.

Comment: Since you're inserting the values in the return statements, the variable `status` is unused and should be deleted, not initialized.  Or you need to rewrite your pseudo-code to set `status` to the different values and then `return status;` at the end.

Comment: Possibly interesting related question: [Should I set errno?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9856822/1717300)

Comment: @hyde the functions are chained and the caller does a call like this. Let me edit in the question

Comment: Your methodology in `GetItDone` is horrible. why use `goto` instead of `return FAIL;`?  Why write the test backwards?  Why use UPPERCASE labels?  All these lessen code readability.

Comment: Just do `if (PASS == status)` and then put the rest of the function in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convention is 0 for success, negative values for various failures, and positive values for predicated successes.

Of these, returning 0 for success is the most frequently observed: doing otherwise would be idiosyncratic.

As for your code, setting the status to a failure code initially and changing it to success as appropriate will afford more program stability.

Comment: Thanks. setting it to FAIL increases stability but the problem is that we need to explicitly assign it to SUCCESS at the end. What is more prevalent in general practice?. I am using this for C++ as well. (can't use exceptions due to some reason)

Comment: The *standard library* convention is 0 for success, -1 for error with `errno` indicating the error code. I wouldn't say there is a general C convention for non-negative to mean success (not to mention, the whole `errno` mechanism is kinda horrible in a few ways), even though it is common (because often negative return value would not make sense otherwise, so it's convenient to use that for returning error).

Answer (score 1):

Returning 0 for success lets you return different values in case of failure

```
#define SUCCESS 0
#define FAILURE_CASE_1 -1
#define FAILURE_CASE_2 -2
```