# How is thread-safe errno initialized if #define substitutes errno symbol?

Tags: c, thread-safety, c99, glibc, errno

I'm trying to understand how **glibc** initializes `errno` without the preprocessor substituting the `errno` symbol.

I first tried to implement a simple version myself based on [csu/errno-loc.c](http://koala.cs.pub.ro/lxr/#glibc+2.9/csu/errno-loc.c) and [csu/errno.c](http://koala.cs.pub.ro/lxr/#glibc+2.9/csu/errno.c):

**myerrno.h**

```
#ifndef MYERRNO_H
#define MYERRNO_H

extern int *myerrno_location(void);
#define myerrno (*myerrno_location())

#endif
```

**myerrno.c**

```
#include "myerrno.h"

static int myerrno = 0;

int *myerrno_location(void){
    return &myerrno;
}
```

However, when I try to compile I receive the following error messages:

```
myerrno.c:3:1: error: function ‘myerrno_location’ is initialized like a variable
myerrno.c:3:12: error: static declaration of ‘myerrno_location’ follows non-static declaration
myerrno.h:4:13: note: previous declaration of ‘myerrno_location’ was here
```

I can tell that the preprocessor is substituting `(*myerrno_location(void))` when it encounters `myerrno` on line 3 -- and naturally this is expected behavior.

I don't understand why this isn't a problem for **glibc**. How do thread-safe implementations of `errno` get around this preprocessor substitution issue without renaming the static `errno` variable?

Comment: is this thread helpful ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694164/is-errno-thread-safe

Comment: In threaded code, there isn't a single location for an `errno` variable; there is one variable per thread, and the function hidden behind the macro is responsible for returning a pointer to the relevant thread-specific variable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Are static variables are shared between threads?

Comment: Yes (static variables in general are shared between threads).  But in a threaded environment, the memory location designated by `errno` is no longer (simply) a static variable; it becomes a thread-local variable — each thread is given its own memory location which 'is' that thread's '`errno`'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I can't find a reference to this in the C99 standard -- unfortunately, I suspect the C99 standard makes no guarantees regarding threads. Is this just the de facto behavior of thread libraries?

Comment: C99 doesn't know what a thread is — you'd have to refer to POSIX to find the definition. C11 does make promises/requirements (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.5 **Errors `<errno.h>`**: `errno` _which expands to a modifiable lvalue(201) that has type `int` and thread local storage
duration, the value of which is set to a positive error number by several library functions.
If a macro definition is suppressed in order to access an actual object, or a program
defines an identifier with the name `errno`, the behavior is undefined._

Comment: And footnote 201 is: _The macro `errno` need not be the identifier of an object. It might expand to a modifiable lvalue
resulting from a function call (for example, `*errno()`)._  The POSIX definition is at [`errno`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/errno.html) and looks compatible with the C11 definition to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixing your issue is as easy as changing the name of your static variable.

```
static int myerrno_variable = 0;

int *myerrno_location(void){
    return &myerrno_variable;
}
```

Notice that your version is still not thread safe since all threads are accessing the same `myerrno_variable`. A real implementation would return a thread specific memory location. In GCC, there is an extension that provides the [`__thread`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Thread_002dLocal.html) storage class. C.11 provides its own version of that called `thread_local`, but it is only available if thread support is provided by the implementation (which can be checked by looking if `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` is defined or not).

```
static __thread int myerrno_variable_gcc;      /* if using GCC */
static thread_local int my_errno_variable_c11; /* if __STD_NO_THREADS__ isn't defined */
```

On a POSIX system without a thread local feature, an implementation could use `pthread_getspecific()` to get a pointer to thread specific data that was allocated for each thread, and set with `pthread_setspecific()`. See [the manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_setspecific.html) for more information.

Comment: So **glibc** is able to use the same name since it uses the GCC extension `__thread`, while most other implementations simply rename the variable?

Comment: @VilhelmGray: Most implementations probably have a similar extension, since the feature has been added to the C.11 standard. However, even if it were not the case, POSIX still provides a mechanism to allocate thread specific storage.

Comment: @VilhelmGray: Oh, **glibc** probably fixes it the same way I told you to fix it. It wouldn't use the same name for the variable and the macro like that. The `__thread` extension allows each thread to have their own private variable that the thread can refer to by the same name.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding the purpose of `__thread` and `thread_local`. If each thread normally has a unique memory location for the same static variable symbol, is the purpose of `__thread` and `thread_local` purely to enable naming a macro and variable the same name? If not, does that mean that in pure C99, there's no standards-guaranteed way for each thread to use a unique memory location for the same variable symbol, without resorting to compiler extensions such as `__thread`?

Comment: Why do you say each thread normally has a unique memory location for the same static variable symbol?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding Jonathan Leffler's comment on my question (`...in a threaded environment, the memory location designated by errno is no longer (simply) a static variable; it becomes a thread-local variable...`). So normally threads *do* use the same memory locations for static variables, and `errno` is unique due to **glibc's** use of `__thread`?

Comment: You misunderstood. @JonathanLeffler was telling you how `errno` specifically behaves in a multi-threaded environment, not how static variables behave in general. The C library implementation has to achieve that behavior. One way is for the implementation to use `__thread` or some equivalent feature.

Comment: Ah, I see where I went wrong now. To solidify my understanding, is `__thread` then the reason the preprocessor macro doesn't substitute `return &errno` with `return &(*(errno_location))` when defining the `errno_location` function?

Comment: If the library implementation declares `errno` with `__thread`, there is no need for a macro. The macro version of `errno` which actually calls a function predates the presence of a `__thread` feature.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34874/discussion-between-vilhelm-gray-and-jxh)