# Making a simple HTTP webserver, using errno to reply with "403 Forbidden" and then redirect to a 403 page?

Tags: c, http, http-status-code-403, errno

I'm making a simple HTTP webserver, and this is the relevant portion of the code:

```
179         stat(path, &rd_perm); /* path contains the full path to the original file request */
180         if(errno == EACCES){ /* We don't have permissions to view the file... */
181                 printf("======> NO READ PERMISSIONS FOR FILE!\n"); /* sanity check */
182                 /* Send the client a 403 Forbidden */
183
184                 send(clients[n], "HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden\r\n\r\n", 26, 0);
185                 strcpy(path, home_dir);
186                 strcpy(&path[strlen(home_dir)], FORBIDDEN);
187
188                 /* After changing the pathname to the "forbidden" page, write that page to the client socket. */
189
190                 if( (fd = open(path, O_RDONLY)) != -1){
191                         while( (bytes_read = read(fd, data_to_send, 1024)) > 0){
192                                 write(clients[n], data_to_send, bytes_read);
193                         }
194                 }
195         }
```

I thought this would be enough, but it's not. I can see two things being wrong here:

- My entry condition, `errno == EACCES`. Since this is a multiprocess webserver, would this be a "safe" and correct way of checking errno's value? Is there a better way?
- Do I still need to send() a "301 Moved Permanently\nLocation: "? This seems wrong, seeing how what I wanted wasn't moved at all - I just didn't have access to it.

I'd wager that my error is the first one, as it doesn't seem to go into the `if` at all. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Multi-*process* or multi-*thread*?

Comment: Also, while plain newline works, the specification actually specifies a carriage-return/newline pair.

Comment: Oh, and never, ever check `errno` unless the function you call actually fails. If the `stat` function doesn't return `-1` then the value of `errno` is undefined.

Comment: By the way, on Linux there is a [`sendfile`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile) system call. Exists (in slightly different form) on [BSD as well](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sendfile&sektion=2) (which means that [Apple OSX also have it](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/sendfile.2.html)).

Comment: And unless you need anything else from the `stat` call, you might as well use `open` to check for access the same way, thereby having one system call less to make.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Multi-process. I'll update the return to \r\n, thanks. As for open(), it was my understanding that open() returns the same error value for `file not found` and `permission denied`, so I wanted to differentiate between the two.

Comment: If the file doesn't exist you would get an `ENOENT` error in both cases.

Comment: And if it's multi-process, then each process have its own `errno`. I actually think even threads have their own separate `errno`. Ah yes it is, see [this old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694164/is-errno-thread-safe).

Comment: Ah, you are correct! It is `ENOENT` for not found, and `EACCES` for no permissions. I must have misread the man page. I'll attempt to do it that way then. Still, the question remains: should I simply send a `HTTP/1.x 403 Forbidden' and let the browser sort it out? Or actuall redirect to a 403 page?

Comment: As for the 403 error, I think it would be more correct to send an 403 error code and let the client handle it.

Comment: Great! Using just `open()` (as opposed to using `stat()` as well), I was able to get close the desired behaviour. If you wish, you can post your answer as well. If not, I will accept the one that @alk posted as it is similar and could have led me to a similar conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`errno` will only by set if `stat()` failed.

So modifiy your code like this:

```
    int result = stat(path, &rd_perm); /* path contains the full path to the original file request */
    if ((-1 == result) && (errno == EACCES)) { /* We don't have permissions to view the file... */
```

---

Each process has its own instance of `errno`.

If going multihreaded make sure to compile using option `-pthread` to have `errno` being declared as thread-local.

Please note that the **compiler option** `-pthread` is different from telling the linker to link against `libpthread` by giving the **linker-option** `-lpthread`.