# What does make errno thread safe?

Tags: c, multithreading, errno

I'm a beginner in C programming and came across `errno` declaration. I read man page of POSIX `errno` and it is required to be thread-local. Here is the quote from man page:

> errno  is  defined  by  the  ISO C standard to be a modifiable lvalue of type int, and must not be explicitly declared; errno may be a macro.  errno is thread-local; setting it in one thread does not
>          affect its value in any other thread.

Now taking a look at `errno.h` I found this:

```
/* Declare the `errno' variable, unless it's defined as a macro by
   bits/errno.h.  This is the case in GNU, where it is a per-thread
   variable.  This redeclaration using the macro still works, but it
   will be a function declaration without a prototype and may trigger
   a -Wstrict-prototypes warning.  */
#ifndef errno
extern int errno;
#endif
```

And to my knowledge it does not look like a thread local variable. What does make `errno` being thread-local?

Comment: That doesn't look like the [thread safe definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694164/is-errno-thread-safe).

Comment: @tadman Ah, I did not notice `define errno (*__errno_location ())` which may be a thread safe.