# Atomics and `errno`: is it reasonable to use C++11 atomics to read a protected errno value?

Tags: c++, atomic, errno

Handling errno is one of the struggle of using POSIX API over a multithreaded environment. Would it be reasonable to use a lock using `std::atomic` like the following one?

```
class FastLock{
    std::atomic_int value;
public:
    FastLock()
    : value{0}{}

    void unlock()
    {
        value.store(0,std::memory_order_release);
    }

    bool try_lock()
    {
        int r = value.exchange(1,std::memory_order_acquire);
        return !r;
    }
};
```

The context would be similar to this:

```
template<typename function, typename ...args>
auto shield(function _fn){
    static FastLock* lk = new FastLock{};
    return [=](args... _v){
        while(lk->try_lock());
        auto ret = std::forward(_fn, _v...);
        auto errval = errno;
        lk->unlock();
        return std::make_pair(ret,errval);
    };
}
```

Would this result in any sort of either undefined behaviour or implementation defined behaviour?

Comment: POSIX errno is thread-safe - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694164/is-errno-thread-safe

Comment: Also, this method is not exception safe. It also burns unnecessary CPU

Comment: @NeilButterworth it is only for a posix version high enough, as specified in the answer.

Comment: @MooingDuck No exception can occur as long as the function is properly set and the return types are primitives. Also, now I have confirmation of the POSIX version which uses threadlocal variable, I added a check to integrate the lock only if it is needed.

Also, it is to be expected that the virtual table access of the function to be obtained at compile time as an optimization.

Comment: @LudovicZenohateLagouardette: I believe you're mistaken. `std::forward(_fn, _v...)` can throw an exception

Comment: @MooingDuck only and only if the called function happen to be throwing. Which is, in the case of POSIX functions, never the case. Also, this was meant as a demonstration purpose, the actual used implementation is different and uses a templated functor instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the old POSIX standard from 1988 used to require `errno` to be a global object, that is no longer the case in later revisions. At least POSIX.1-2001 requires `errno` to be thread local. I suspect that this was already required by POSIX.1c-1995 which specifies POSIX threads, but I don't have access to that document, so I cannot verify.

I would not expect that a POSIX system that supports C++11 wouldn't also support POSIX 2001 and as such, the use of C++11 atomics seems unlikely to be necessary.

That said, while C standard doesn't require `errno` to be a global object (at least, C99 doesn't) it also doesn't guarantee thread locality of `errno`. So, locking `errno` might be necessary on non-POSIX systems or old POSIX systems that don't provide thread locality. And if for some reason the platform does support C++11, then C++11 atomics might be the ideal choice for implementing the lock - or it might not be. At least in theory.

Note that to guarantee thread safety, you would have to make sure that all calls to functions that might set `errno` must use the lock. If you use any libraries that might use such standard functions, you must lock calls to such functions as well.

Comment: Libraries? What's that? Can you eat it? You may have noticed I am a time traveler of sorts to have missed such a change to POSIX