# Is there a way to change an array size using malloc and free functions only?

Tags: c, malloc, free, memory-reallocation

As homework, I have to write a function that changes an array's size using `malloc` and `free` functions only.

I know how to do it with `realloc`, but I don't know how to do it with `malloc`.

```
typedef struct{
    int *tab;
    int size;
}arr;
```

and I need to write this function :

```
void changeSizeDyn(arr *Dyn_arr, int size){
    //
}
```

As mentioned in the homework: it requires only one reallocation and only one memory release, and only one copy of the elements from the old array.
I searched a lot but only found results using `realloc`.

Is it even possible to do that without using `realloc`?

Comment: Just allocate a new array, copy the contents, and free the old one.  That's what realloc does.

Comment: Well, probably the bits in an optimized c library are better than that. If contiguous memory is available, probably it won't touch the old contents, and just extend them. If there isn't, I guess it will do exactly that. But the concept is that.

Comment: @alk Derp. that makes considerable sense seeing the structure. Redacted, and thanks for keeping me honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct Arr {
        int *tab;
        ptrdiff_t nmemb;
};
```

Let's say you allocated the array like this initially:

```
struct Arr x;

x.nmemb = 7;
x.tab = malloc(sizeof(*x.tab) * x.nmemb);
```

You should realloc it with this function:

```
void change_size_dyn(struct Arr *dyn_arr, ptrdiff_t nmemb)
{
        struct Arr old;
        ptrdiff_t cp_nmemb;

        if (!dyn_arr)
                return;
        old = *dyn_arr;

        if (nmemb <= 0)
                goto err;
        dyn_arr->tab = malloc(sizeof(*dyn_arr->tab) * nmemb);
        dyn_arr->nmemb = nmemb;

        cp_sz = MIN(old.nmemb, nmemb);
        memcpy(dyn_arr->tab, old.tab, cp_nmemb);
        free(old.tab);

        return;
err:
        dyn_arr->tab = NULL;
        dyn_arr->nmemb = 0;
        free(old.tab);
}
```

Which should be called this way:

```
change_size_dyn(&x, 9);
```

You can use this function even for the first allocation (although you should set to `NULL` and `0` both values first). You also don't need to add a free; an input of 0 would do it for you, just like `realloc` would do:

```
int main(void)
{
        struct Arr x = {0};

        change_size_dyn(&x, 5);
        /* ... */
        change_size_dyn(&x, 9);
        /* ... */

cleanup:
        change_size_dyn(&x, 0);
        return 0;
}
```

If you pass a structure where  `dyn_arr->nmemb` is already a negative value (shouldn't happen), the behaviour is undefined (that negative value would go into `memcpy`, which would be wrapped into a very high `size_t`, which would overflow the arrays).  I didn't want to check for that because it would be unnecessary in any non-buggy scenario.

Comment: A function having the return type void may not return an expression of the value NULL. See your code if (!dyn_arr)
                return NULL;

Comment: Why the heck do you use `ptrdiff_t `?

Comment: @alk Because it's what it represents, it is the pointer difference between one past the last element in the array and the first element. It's not a size in bytes, which is the only case I use `size_t`. So I use `size_t` for `unsigned char` arrays, where you mean the size in bytes (so that's for `memcpy` and it's family of functions almost exclusively), and `ptrdiff_t` for the rest of arrays.

Comment: I see. Interesting argumentation, indeed.

Comment: @alk I renamed `size` to `nmemb` which makes more sense with `ptrdiff_t` :)

Answer (score 5):

1. Allocate memory of the new size using malloc.
2. Copy all bytes from the old memory to the new memory. You can do that in a loop, you don't actually need to use functions for this (if that is the assignment).
3. Free the old memory.

Comment: Can you provide some code? Because I'm not sure I understand how this exactly works.

Answer (score 1):

The function is not simple as it seems at first glance.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct
{
    int *tab;
    int size;
} arr;

int changeSizeDyn( arr *Dyn_arr, int size )
{
    int success = 1;

    if ( Dyn_arr->size != size )
    {
        int *tmp = NULL;

        if ( size != 0 )
        {
            tmp = malloc( size * sizeof( int ) );
            success = tmp != NULL;

            if ( success )
            {
                int n = 0;

                if ( Dyn_arr->size != 0 )
                {
                    n = size < Dyn_arr->size ? size : Dyn_arr->size;

                    memcpy( tmp, Dyn_arr->tab, n * sizeof( int ) );
                }

                if ( n < size ) memset( tmp + n, 0, ( size - n ) * sizeof( int ) );
            }
        }

        if ( success )
        {
            free( Dyn_arr->tab );

            Dyn_arr->tab = tmp;
            Dyn_arr->size = size;
        }
    }

    return success;
}

int main( void )
{
    arr a = { NULL, 0 };
    int size = 10;

    if ( changeSizeDyn( &a, size ) )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) a.tab[i] = i;

        for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a.tab[i] );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    size = 5;

    if ( changeSizeDyn( &a, size ) )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) a.tab[i] = i;

        for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a.tab[i] );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    size = 0;

    if ( changeSizeDyn( &a, size ) )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) a.tab[i] = i;

        for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a.tab[i] );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    assert( a.tab == NULL && a.size == 0 );
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4
```

The function has a return type `int` to signal whether its call was successful or not. You need a method to determine whether a function call was successful. Otherwise it will be impossible to determine this. So to use the type `void` as the return type of the function is a bad idea.

The function by default sets all new elements that do not correspond to the elements of the old array to zero. In fact it is not necessary but makes the usage of the structure more clear.

If the user passes the size equal to 0 then the function just free the old array and sets the data member `tab` to `NULL`.

If the new size and old size of the array are equal each other the function does nothing.

Take into account that it is much better to declare the data member `size` of the structure as having type `size_t`. Otherwise you need to add a check in the function that `size` is not negative. I did not do that because I suppose that you will indeed use the type `size_t` instead of the type `int` in the structure (and function) declaration.

Comment: "*Otherwise it will be impossible to determine this*" Hm? One can fallback to using `errno`.

Comment: @alk errno is a bad idea for using in a multithreading environment.

Comment: I assume it's save to use `errno` in a multithreaded environment at least for POSIX compliant systems. Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1694170/694576 Still, I'd agreed on, that doing so is not nice.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is it even possible to do that without using `realloc`?*

Sure it is.

You could for example do it like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc () and free () and EXIT_xxx macros. */
#include <stdio.h> /* for perror */

typedef struct{
  int *tab;
  size_t size; /* Prefer using size_t for (memory) sizes over using a 
                  signed int. */
} arr;

void changeSizeDyn(arr *parr, size_t size)
{
  if (!parr && !parr->tab)
  {
    errno = EINVAL;
  }
  else
  {
    arr tmp = {
      malloc(size * sizeof *tmp.tab),
      size
    };

    if (tmp.size && !tmp.tab)
    {
      perror("malloc() failed");
    }
    else
    {      
      for (
        size_t m = (tmp.size < parr->size) ?tmp.size :parr->size, i = 0;
        i < m; 
        ++i)
      {
        tmp.tab[i] = parr->tab[i];
      }

      free(parr->tab);

      *parr = tmp;

      errno = 0;
    }
  }
}

/* A main() to test the above: */
int main(void)
{
  const size_t s = 42;
  arr a = {
    malloc(s * sizeof *a.tab),
    s
  };

  if (a.size && !a.tab)
  {
    perror("malloc() failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /* populate a.tab[0] to a.tab[a.size - 1] here. */

  changeSizeDyn(&a, 43);
  if (0 != errno)
  {
    perror("changeSizeDyn() failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /* Use a.tab[0] to a.tab[a.size - 1] here. */

  free(a.tab);
  a.size = 0;
}
```

Comment: First time i saw initialization code like this,arr a = {
    malloc(s * sizeof *a.tab),
    s
  };  :) :)

Answer (score -2):

```
void *onlymallocrealloc(void *ptr, size_t oldsize, size_t newsize)
{
    void *newmem = malloc(newsize);

    if(ptr && newmem)
    {
        memcpy(newmem, ptr, oldsize);
        free(ptr);
    }
    return newmem;
}
```

and for your type (slightly changed)

```
typedef struct{
    int size;
    int tab[];
}arr;


arr *onlymalloc(arr *ptr, size_t newsize)
{
    ptr = onlymallocrealloc(ptr, ptr -> size * sizoef(ptr -> tab[0]) + sizeof(*ptr), newsize * sizoef(ptr -> tab[0]) + sizeof(*ptr));

    if(ptr)
    {
        ptr -> size = newsize;
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

## edit if the function has to be void

```
void onlymallocrealloc(void **ptr, size_t oldsize, size_t newsize)
{
    void *newmem = malloc(newsize);

    if(*ptr && newmem)
    {
        memcpy(newmem, *ptr, oldsize);
        free(*ptr);
        *ptr = newmem;
    }
}

void onlymalloc(arr **ptr, size_t newsize)
{
    onlymallocrealloc(&ptr, *ptr -> size * sizoef(*ptr -> tab[0]) + sizeof(**ptr), newsize * sizoef(*ptr -> tab[0]) + sizeof(**ptr));

    if(*ptr)
    {
        *ptr -> size = newsize;
    }
}
```

Comment: The arguments and return type (void) must stay as presented.

Comment: I think the array is `tab`, and not `Dyn_arr`, because if not, the prototype doesn't make sense. So `ptr->tab` would be the array that has to be reallocated.

Comment: @P__J__ Yes. But your function needs a ** and the prototype he needs needs a *. So this does not answer his problem

Comment: See my answer to see what I'm saying

Comment: @P__J__ This is not the place to show your frustration. Learn to how to talk to people first then answer.

Comment: @KBlr your previous comment was rather rude