# How to check strtol overflow without errno?

Tags: c, embedded, rtos

Given the following example parsing a string that only contains valid numeric characters, but is to large for type `long int`[0].

```
char *endptr = NULL;
long int val = strtol("0xfffffffffffffffffffffffff", &endptr, 0);
```

It is my understanding that the only way to catch this error is to check if `errno` is set[1]. 
Even though `errno` is supposed to be thread safe[2], this is not the case in most real-time embedded systems[3] where `errno` is a global `int` - is this correct? In that case, `errno` can not be trusted as it could have been modified from interrupt[4] context.

Is there a way to catch this error without using `errno` or is there another workaround? Implementing a custom `strto*` do not seems like sane solution, but perhaps there is no other way?

[0] Similar example could be constructed for other functions in `strto*` family such as `strtod`, `strtof`, `strtold`, `strtoll`, `strtoul` and `strtoull`.

[1] http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html

[2] [Is errno thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694164/is-errno-thread-safe) (also related question)

[3] Example in a "bare metal" project or in a low level RTOS such as Apache mynewt, Zephyr or FreeRTOS.

[4] Modified from interrupt or other context that the OS scheduler might provide. I believe these typically only manages the stack and nothing more.

Comment: is your program multithreaded?

Comment: The man page says of `strtol` *"When the representation would cause an overflow, they return LONG_MAX or LONG_MIN."* And please see C18 §7.22.1.4

Comment: ...so unless `LONG_MAX` or `LONG_MIN` are acceptable inputs, these values tell you there was overflow without using `errno`.

Comment: Calling anything that might set errno in an interrupt context, is ill advised in any case.  In a multithreaded environment, it is possible that `errno` is _thread local storage_, but that might depend on your library implementation and its correct integration with your RTOS or thread-library.  If they are from independent vendors or projects, there are no guarantees unless you have implemented the thread-safety yourself.

Comment: @OznOg if you count interrupts as multithreaded, then yes.

Comment: I think you don't call things that use errno on interrupts handlers, do you? so, not sure you have a problem...

Comment: @OznOg I agree,  errno should not be set from interrupts but it can be hard to guarantee it never happen. It is however reasonably that errno is set from another context such as a job, task or whatever your RTOS might call them,

Comment: You may have multitasking on single CPU/threading context, BTW, If you have __real__ multithreaded context, you need memory barriers (or atomic errno) why you lib may not provide.

Answer (score 1):

> How to check `strto...()` overflow without errno?

First, I'd doubt OP's assertion: "this is not the case in most real-time embedded systems[2] where errno is a global int - is this correct?">  Be that as it may, here are some ideas.

1. For floating point (FP), re-writing `strto...()` is prone to failure. If your FP supports *infinity*, simply use `isinf()` to detect overflow - even if the input string was "INFINITY" - or test for such *infinity* strings.

Overflow for small values near 0.0 is a rabbit hole of issues for `strto...()`.  I assume OP is not looking for *overflow* there.

2. For integer `strto...()`, re-writing is not so hard.  Easy to find good source code.  If one still wants to avoid that for *signed* `strto...()`, call both as in `strtol()` and `strtoul()` and compare results.  Overflow in the functions return results that do not compare.  Works for in `long` range negatives like `"-123"` too.  For *unsigned* `strto...()` - have to think on that.

   bool strtol_no_errno(const char *s, long *num) {
   *num = strtol(s, NULL, 0);
   unsigned long unum = strtoul(s, NULL, 0);
   return unum == (unsigned long) *num;
   }
3. For integer `strto(u)l()`, when `long` is narrower than `long long`, just call `strto(u)ll()` and test if result is in range.

---

Test

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( ) {
  char buf[100] = "-1";
  for (int i = 0; i<21; i++) {
    long num;
    bool ok = strtol_no_errno(buf + 1, &num);
    printf("%30s %d %ld\n", buf + 1, ok, num);
    ok = strtol_no_errno(buf + 0, &num);
    printf("%30s %d %ld\n", buf, ok, num);
    strcat(buf, "0");
  }
}
```

Output

```
                         1 1 1
                        -1 1 -1
                        10 1 10
                       -10 1 -10
...
        100000000000000000 1 100000000000000000
       -100000000000000000 1 -100000000000000000
       1000000000000000000 1 1000000000000000000
      -1000000000000000000 1 -1000000000000000000
      10000000000000000000 0 9223372036854775807
     -10000000000000000000 0 -9223372036854775808
     100000000000000000000 0 9223372036854775807
    -100000000000000000000 0 -9223372036854775808
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is to sanitize the input. For example, if the string length without "0x" is larger than `sizeof(long)*2`, then the input is obviously too large. So start by verifying that.

Also make sure that if the input has exactly string length of `sizeof(long)*2`, then `input[0]` must be `'7'` or smaller for signed `long`. Or in case `input[0]` is `'-'`, check `input[1]`. (Some 2's complement trickery to consider here, I'll leave that to you.)

With the above sanity checks, it shouldn't be possible to get an overflow. But if you do, the function is guaranteed to return `LONG_MAX` (or `LONG_MIN` for underflow). Also, `endptr` is set to the beginning of the input string in case of such errors. So you can check if the conversion failed like this:

```
if(val != LONG_MAX) 
{ 
  /* OK, normal case */ 
}
else // val == LONG_MAX
{
  if(endptr != input &&
     (size_t)(endptr-input) == sizeof(long)*2))
  {
    /* OK, input was LONG_MAX but no overflow */ 
  }
  else
  {
    /* overflow error */
  }
}
```

This assuming that `input` doesn't have the `0x` prefix - if it has, you'll have to tweak the code accordingly.

Same check is needed for underflow.

Comment: `endptr` is not set to the beginning of the string there is an overflow. If the string starts with optional white space and characters forming an integer constant with some controls according to the base, then `endptr` is set to the first character after that, regardless of overflow. Only if no characters founding an integer constant are found is `endptr` set to the beginning of the string. So `endptr` is useless for detecting overflow. Additionally, if the length of the string after `0x` exceeds `sizeof(long)*2`, that does not guarantee overflow. There may be leading zeros.

Comment: There is an excess closing parenthesis in the second `if`.

Comment: The question gives an example starting with `0x` but does not assert all inputs will have it.